# $\mu$-integrals of functions indexed by stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am studying stopping times and I found a proof with a couple of passages that I can't explain/prove myself.

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mathcal{A}_n,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite filtered measure space where $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Let $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be a sequence of functions such that $u_n \in \mathcal{L}^1(A_n)$. Now assume $\sigma,\tau$ are bounded stopping times such that $\sigma \leq \tau \leq N$ for some $N$. Define $\{\sigma = n\}:=\{x \in X:\sigma(x)=n\}$. The first passage is

> $$\int|u_\sigma|d\mu=\sum_{n=0}^N\int_{\{\sigma = n\}}|u_n|d\mu$$

My attempt to explain this goes like this:
$$\int|u_\sigma|d\mu=\int\mathbb{I}_X|u_\sigma|d\mu=\int \mathbb{I}_{\{\sigma \leq N\}}|u_\sigma|d\mu= \\ =\int\mathbb{I}_{\cup_n^N\{\sigma =n\}}|u_\sigma|d\mu= \int\sum_{n=0}^N\mathbb{I}_{\{\sigma=n\}}|u_\sigma|d\mu= \\ =\sum_{n=0}^N\int \mathbb{I}_{\{\sigma = n\}}|u_\sigma|d\mu = \sum_{n=0}^N\int_{\{\sigma = n\}}|u_n|d\mu$$

The other passage is

> $$\int \sum_{n=\sigma}^{\tau-1}(u_{n}-u_{n+1})d\mu=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\int (u_n-u_{n+1})\mathbb{I}_{\{\sigma = n\}\cap \{n < \tau\}}d\mu$$

And here I am quite confused about how and why the stopping times came out of the sum.

Would be very grateful for any help.

---

**Edit**: I think that $\{\sigma = n\}$ might be a typo and it should be $\{\sigma \geq n\}$. However, I checked the errata of the book on its website and it's not there.

Comment: Have you tried writing $\sum_{n = \sigma}^{\tau - 1} (u_{n} - u_{n + 1}) = \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} (u_{n} - u_{n +1}) 1_{\{n \geq \sigma\}} 1_{\{n < \tau\}}$?